# How do I copy the selected option value to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

If the input box is hidden, is it not possible to copy?

When the input type is hidden, it cannot be copied.
So I hide the input using position.
Is there a better way to copy select option values?

I don't know if there is any more way.
I need your help.

```js
var optionSelectedText = $(".copy-url-sel option:selected").text();
var $copyUrlSelText = $('#copyUrlSelText'); // input

$copyUrlSelText.val(optionSelectedText); // basic setting

$("#copyUrlSel").on('change', function(){
  optionSelectedText = $("#copyUrlSel option:selected").text();
  $copyUrlSelText.val(optionSelectedText);
});
```

```css
.ui-copy-select .wrap {position:relative;}
.ui-copy-select #copyUrlSelText{position:fixed; left:-9999px;}
.ui-copy-select select {padding-right:60px;color:#3283F6;width:calc(100% - 70px);display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;margin-right:5px;}
.ui-copy-select select::placeholder {color:#3283F6;}
.ui-copy-select button {background:#F7F7F7;position:relative;top:0;right:0;padding:0 .9rem;height:32px;line-height:30px;border-radius:.2rem;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;padding:inherit .9rem;}
.ui-copy-select button:focus, .ui-copy-select button:active {opacity:0.8;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- HTML -->
<!-- copy url / ver.select -->

<div class="ui-copy-select">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="" id="copyUrlSelText">
    <!-- select -->
    <select
      name=""
      class="form-control copy-url-sel"
      id="copyUrlSel"
    >
      <option value="" selected>
        http://www.inucreative.com/
      </option>
      <option value="">
        http://naver.com/
      </option>
      <option value="">
        http://www.inucreative.com/main.html
      </option>
    </select>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn primary"
      id="btnCopyUrlSel"
    >
      copy
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the code snippet below will help you.

```
var copyTarget = document.getElementById("copyUrlSelText");
copyTarget.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/yasgo/pen/YzGKErz?editors=1111

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.execCommand("copy");` to copy the content. Here's a working example:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ui-copy-select">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" value="" id="copyUrlSelText">
    <!-- select -->
    <select
      name=""
      class="form-control copy-url-sel"
      id="copyUrlSel"
    >
      <option value="" selected>
        http://www.inucreative.com/
      </option>
      <option value="">
        http://naver.com/
      </option>
      <option value="">
        http://www.inucreative.com/main.html
      </option>
    </select>
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn primary"
      id="btnCopyUrlSel"
    >
      copy
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var optionSelectedText = $(".copy-url-sel option:selected").text();
  copyToClipboard(optionSelectedText.trim());
  $("#copyUrlSel").on('change', function(){
     optionSelectedText = $("#copyUrlSel option:selected").text();
     copyToClipboard(optionSelectedText.trim())
  });
function copyToClipboard(text) {
    $("#copyUrlSelText").val(text).select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
}
```

**Codepen** - https://codepen.io/askannan/pen/BaLBmwQ